# Find multiplicative inverse in Galois field $2^8$ using extended Euclides algorithms

Tags: finite-field

I'm dealing with Galois fields $GF(2^{8})$ and need help finding a
polynomial $r^{-1}(x)$  such that $r^{-1}(x) r(x) \equiv 1 \mod m(x)$, where:

- $m(x) = x^{8} + x^{4} + x^{3} + x + 1$
- $r(x) = u(x) - q(x) \cdot m(x)$
- $u(x) = s(x) \cdot t(x)$
- $s(x) = x^{7} + x^{5} + x^{4} + x$
- $t(x) = x^{4} + x^{2} + 1$

Thus:

- $u(x) = x^{11} + x^{8} + x^{6} + x^{4} + x^{3} + x$
- $q(x) = x^{3} + 1$
- $r(x) = -x^{7} - x^{4} - x^{3} + 1 \mod 2 = x^{7} + x^{4} + x^{3} + 1$

### what I have tried

I've attempted to find out $r^{-1}(x)$ but failed.

Here is what I've tried:

From Euclides's algorithm:

\begin{align*}
    u(x) &= q(x) \cdot m(x) + r(x) \\
    m(x) &= q_{2}(x) \cdot r(x) + r_{2}(x) \\
         &= x \cdot r(x) + (-x^{5} + x^{3} + 1 \mod 2) \\
         &= x \cdot r(x) + ( x^{5} + x^{3} + 1) \\
    r(x) &= q_{3}(x) \cdot r_{2}(x) + r_{3}(x) \\
         &= (x^{2} - 1 \mod 2) \cdot r_{2}(x) + (x^{4} + 2 x^{3} - x^{2} + 2 \mod 2) \\
         &= (x^{2} + 1) \cdot r_{2}(x) + (x^{4} + x^{2}) \\
r_{2}(x) &= q_{4}(x) \cdot r_{3}(x) + r_{4}(x) \\
         &= x \cdot r_{3}(x) + 1 \\
r_{3}(x) &= q_{5}(x) \cdot r_{4}(x) + r_{5}(x) \\
         &= (x^{4} + x^{2}) \cdot r_{4}(x) + 0
\end{align*}

We have:

\begin{align*}
  q_{2}(x) &= x \\
  q_{3}(x) &= x^{2} + 1 \\
  q_{4}(x) &= x \\
  q_{5}(x) &= x^{4} + x^{2} \\
  r_{2}(x) &= x^{5} + x^{3} + 1 \\
  r_{3}(x) &= x^{4} + x^{2} \\
  r_{4}(x) &= 1 \\
  r_{5}(x) &= 0
\end{align*}

Thus:

\begin{align*}
1 &= r_{4}(x) \\
  &= r_{2}(x) - q_{4}(x)r_{3}(x) \\
  &= r_{2}(x) - q_{4}(x)\big(r(x) - q_{3}(x)r_{2}(x)\big) \\
  &=  \big(-q_{4}(x)\big) r(x) +
      \big(1 + q_{3}(x)\big) r_{2}(x) \\
  &=  \big(-q_{4}(x)\big) r(x) +
      \big(1 + q_{3}(x)\big) \big(m(x) - q_{2}(x)r(x)\big) \\
  &=  \Big(-q_{4}(x) - q_{2}(x) - q_{2}(x)q_{3}(x)\Big) r(x) +
      \Big(1 + q_{r}(x)\Big) m(x)
\end{align*}

So, we get:

\begin{align*}
  r^{-1}(x)
  & = - q_{4}(x) - q_{2}(x) - q_{2}(x)q_{3}(x) & \mod 2 \\
  & = - x - x - x(x^{2} + 1)           & \mod 2 \\
  & = - x - x - x^{3} - x              & \mod 2 \\
  & = - x^{3} - 3x                     & \mod 2 \\
  & = x^{3} + x
\end{align*}

But, this is wrong because when I compute $r^{-1}(x) r(x) \mod m(x)$
the result is not 1

Comment: where does the "mod 2" come from?

Comment: @SamGinrich the mod 2 is because we are in $GF(2^n)$

Comment: $GF(2^n)$ is something modulo $m(x)$

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what I did wrong.. I do am having trouble understanding the algorithm (that's why i need help). I computed $\mod 2$ because I thought the polynomial coefficients had to be in $\{0,1\}$ since we're dealing with bytes. If you can explain what I did wrong I'd appreciate it!

Comment: I guess it's wanted the polynomial inverse of $s(x)\cdot t(x)$ modulo $m(x)$, and towards this you define $r(x)=s(x)\cdot t(x)\bmod m(x)$. Without this definition I fail to make sense of _thus_ $u(x)=s(x)\cdot t(x)$.

Comment: @fgrieu I forgot to mention that $u(x) = s(x) \cdot t(x)$ because it is defined this way in the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem is where
$$r_{2}(x) - q_{4}(x)\big(r(x) - q_{3}(x)r_{2}(x)\big)$$becomes$$\big(-q_{4}(x)\big) r(x) +\big(1 + q_{3}(x)\big) r_{2}(x)$$when that should to be$$\big(-q_{4}(x)\big) r(x) +\big(1 + q_{4}(x)\cdot q_{3}(x)\big) r_{2}(x)$$

---

Independently, I think it would be best to use the significantly simpler algorithm [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Simple_algebraic_field_extensions), which needs to keep track of only 4 variables.

Comment: Thank you! That was where I got wrong! God bless you because I was having so much stress with this question...

Comment: By the way, I implemented the simpler algorithm you talked about instead of the one I was using previously.... thanks!